# How to write a simple image load function in ios using opencv

Tags: c++, iphone, ios, opencv, computer-vision

Can I write a simple C++ code for image load using Opencv in ios. Can you point me to some simple project where I can make a start.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at my simple starter projects on GitHub...

[OpenCVSquares](http://www.github.com/foundry/OpenCVSquares)

[OpenCVCircles](http://www.github.com/foundry/OpenCVCircles)

The image *loading* is done in cocoa/ objective C, the  openCV *processing* is in C++ using the openCV framework. There is a small obectiveC++ wrapper object to pass image data between the two, and to translate image formats from iOS ( UIImage) and openCV (cv::Mat).

You don't have to do it like this, but I find it helps to keep the C++ code apart from the objective-C code as much as possible.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I would like to know we can send this for review also to apple and release as product? sorry if the question is a silly one am a newbie.

Comment: I haven't done this myself but you shouldn't have a problem. Go to the app store and search for "openCV" - you'll see an intriguing range of apps